# Clean invalid image form/correct redirect

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I develop a pet-ptoject, kinda simple image sharing service and encountered such difficulty. What I have and what trying to get.

1. A homepage which is rendered by 'index' view with model form and 3 queries of images.
2. A user is supposed to select his image from his disk to upload, enter image title (optionally) and press Upload button.
3. In case of invalid image submission (non-image format of due to restrictions) my app should render homepage again with error message, empty form to prevent rise browser's caution about double action.

Here's that view from views.py

```
def index(request):
# Main page view
form = ImageForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
images_recent = Image.objects.order_by('-upl_date')[:IMAGE_COUNT]
images_popular = Image.objects.order_by('-rev_count')[:IMAGE_COUNT]
images_like = Image.objects.order_by('-like_count')[:IMAGE_COUNT]

if form.is_valid():
    image = form.save(commit=False)
    image.user = request.user
    image.img = request.FILES['img']
    image.desc = request.POST.get('desc')
    image.slug = slug_gen()
    image.save()
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, _('Yee haw! Your amazing image uploaded'))
    return redirect('pyxchange:index')

context = {
    'form': form,
    'images_recent': images_recent,
    'images_popular': images_popular,
    'images_like': images_like
}

return render(request, 'pyxchange/index.html', context)
```

What have I fix/add here to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: you forgot to say what the problem is

Comment: Sorry. The problem is I don't know how to get an action which brings me to a home page with clean form and error message same time.

Comment: but why do you want to clear the form and why do you want to redirect to the home page?

Comment: I see workflow this way:
— initial rendering (opening) home page
— choose image in form from disk and add title for it, submit form
— if valid, save image, redirect to home page and show SUCCESS message there
— if not valid, redirect to home page with ERROR message, clean form and this is the start point for correct or next image upload

Is this look strange?